# Generic function that accepts const and non-const data and related function

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

To make more sence for the question title consider the following code:

```
template <typename T>
void write(const T& /*data*/)
{
    // use data as const
}

template <typename T>
void read(T& /*data*/)
{
    // modify data
}

struct S { 
    int a;
    int b;
    // a lot of primitive types here
};

void output(const S& s)
{
    write(s.a);
    write(s.b);
    // ...
}

void input(S& s)
{
    read(s.a);
    read(s.b);
    // ...
}

int main()
{
    S s;
    input(s);
    output(s);
}
```

I have `write` and `read` functions that manipulate primitive data like  `int`, `double` etc. I have several struct types like `S` that contains a lot of primitive data members, and I need to input and output such types via corresonding functions `input` and `output` (there are many of overloads for distinct types). As you can see the content of `output` and `input` functions mostly the same, only the inner functions and type constness are different. I would like to make some generic (template) function `use` to eliminate code duplicates from `input`/`output` functions.

I think the template signature will be the following (but I can miss something):

```
template <typename F, typename T>
void use(T& t) { ... }
```

So I could call the `use` function from `input`/`output` like this:

```
use<write, S>(s); // in output function
use<read, S>(s);  // in input fuction
```

How to archive this (or similar) behaviour to eliminate code duplications? I'm using C++14.

Comment: Can't it just be `use(T t)` and let `T` be `T&` or `const T&` as appropriate?

Comment: On what basis do you consider that  `use<write, S>(s)`  is better than `write(s)` (or even the more explicit `write<S>(s)`)?

Comment: @Peter: simple, imagine seralization/deserialization code for a struct. You want to list the members once, not twice.

Comment: FWIW, if you want to serialize a bunch of different types, look into boost serialize: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html

Comment: @VittorioRomeo - I understand what the question is about.  But the solution sought still requires the statements doing reading and writing operations to be distinct.   The members might be listed once, but they are used in more complex statements that must be different for reading and writing.

Comment: There are some reflexive libraries which allow to visit member of struct. (MACRO are needed to declare the struct to have the reflexivity though).

Comment: @Jarod42: that is not true in C++17. Google for "`magic_get`" - that can do simple struct introspection.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo: Indeed. I don't know why I though about name (which require MACRO), that OP doesn't need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template <typename S, typename F>
void use(S&& s, F&& f)
{
    f(s.a);
    f(s.b);
    f(s.c);
}
```

Usage:

```
use(s, [](const auto& x){ write(x); });
use(s, [](auto& x)      { read(x); });
```

[**live example on wandbox.org**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/dXDBncIdGXdAjCdV)

---

If you need multiple types:

```
template <typename S, typename Target>
using EnableFor = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<S>, Target>>;

template <typename S, typename F>
auto use(S&& s, F&& f) -> EnableFor<S, S0>
{
    f(s.a);
    f(s.b);
    f(s.c);
}

template <typename S, typename F>
auto use(S&& s, F&& f) -> EnableFor<S, S1>
{
    f(s.d);
    f(s.e);
    f(s.f);
}
```

Usage:

```
int main()
{
    S0 s0; 
    use(s0, [](const auto& x){ write(x); });
    use(s0, [](auto& x)      { read(x); });

    S1 s1;
    use(s1, [](const auto& x){ write(x); });
    use(s1, [](auto& x)      { read(x); });
}
```

[**live example on wandbox.org**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/vgGHIV6NNduYevPA)

Comment: What should I do with another type e.g. `S1 { int x, int y; };`?. I.e. there is no `a`,`b`,`c` fields.

Comment: You write another `use` function for that. You can constrain `S` to be `S0` or `S1` so that they overload.

Comment: I thought in terms of template function there should be a specialization, isn't it so?

Comment: @älёxölüt A better solution will come in the future with reflection, but for now this is all you've got.

Comment: @älёxölüt: specialization doesn't play nicely with function templates and perfect forwarding. I'd use two overloads with `enable_if`, or Concepts in C++20.

Comment: Could you please expand your answer for using several `S` types simultaneously as I described in the first comment and question itself?

Comment: In case of c++14 I need to use `is_same<...>::value` instead of `is_same_v` which comes from c++17.

Answer (score 0):

You can define an interface of the template being used:

```
template<class M, class S>
void use(S &&s) {
    M::method(s.a);
    M::method(s.b);
};
```

Then implement it:

```
template <typename T>
void write(const T& /*data*/)
{
    // use data as const
}

struct writer {
    template <typename T>
    static void method(const T& t)
    {
        write(t);
    }
};
```

Now you can use it:

```
use<writer>(s);
```

For `read`, it's the same:

```
struct reader {
    template <typename T>
    static void method(T& t)
    {
        read(t);
    }
};

use<reader>(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I understood what you want, but it is impossible. Currently there is no way to implement in C++ generic streaming for all classes. One would need access to information like number of fields the class has, their relative address as well as type in compile time.

Currently they are working on adding this to C++ for many years, seek Reflection TS. As far as I know it won't be ready for C++20.

However, you can organize your code so that each read/write method is easy to implement. For example:

```
class A : public B, public C
{
   private:
   vector<int> m_v;
   int m_x;
};
```

Then implement write for it as

```
template<>
void write(const A& a)
{
     write((const B&)a);
     write((const C&)a);
     write(a.m_v);
     write(a.m_x);
}
```

While for common data structures like `std::vector<T>` implement write via `write<T>`. It takes time but making it technical and using redirections can save a lot of code and time.

(You need to make `write` a friend function, or a member function to let it access private members)

Comment: *"One would need access to information like number of fields the class has, their relative address as well as type in compile time.*" This is possible since C++17. Google for "`magic_get`".

Comment: Interesting, it could indeed solve half the problems (one still needs to work out the problem of identifying the exact location of Fields as alignment rules make it non-trivial). 

Unfortunately, `magic_get` won't work whenever the class derives from anything else - only for plain structs / classes.